# Is there a method to actually rotate data within XArray objects?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm currently working with weather data in the Python module of XArray, comparing between short-term model forecasts and observational data over a specific region of the U.S. The model data is stored in .nc files; the observational data is contained in ArcGIS-originated .asc files.

When plotting the data through matplotlib, it is evident that the observational data has become rotated so that it is mapped incorrectly relative to model data from the same time period. To ensure that the error is with the dataset and not the plot, I'm calculating the center of mass for the precipitation field in each instance; the center of mass is also significantly different between the two items, which means that the error exists in the observational file itself.

As a result, I was wondering if there is a known method to actually rotate the observational data field (stored as a data variable within an XArray dataset) by changing the locations of specific entries while preserving the shape of the set. I've already tried transpositions, which did not successfully fix the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is this `swap_dims`? If not, can you add a toy example of what you'd like to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I had a simmilar problem. Specyfing coordinates explicitly helped in my case:

```
model_arr.mean(dim='time').plot(x='Longitude',y='Latitude')
```